# How to configure SOAPACTION header with an ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, soap

I've an issue using a SOAP Webservice.
Basically I just want to verify some authentification information with a simple form : login / password.

I create an Ajax script with jQuery to call that webservice but I've an issue with the SOAPAction header (error 500).
I don't know if it could help, I'm working with wordpress. And I did some good test with the API on SOAPUI.

I just don't know how to fix it. 
Thanks for your help (if you need more info, please ask me) !

```
var soapLogin = xmlString;   

$.ajax({
url: myUrl,
type: "POST",
dataType: "xml",
data: soapLogin,
contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
processData: false,
success: onSuccess,
error: onError
});
function onSuccess(data){
  console.log(data);
}
function onError(data){
   console.log('nop');
}
```

**EDIT :**
In case someone is having the same issue :
I didn't find how to deal with js. That's why I try PHP and it works like a charm.

```
if($_POST['nom']){
        $client = new SoapClient($SOAPURL, array('trace' => 1));
        $client->method1('login', 'password');
        echo "Response:\n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "\n";
    }
```

Comment: Use the `header` property of `$.ajax()` to add a custom header. See the duplicate for more information

Comment: Thansk, I already used that way, but it gives me that error : Unsupported HTTP request header: Soapaction
I also have the console return : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.